# git doesn't fetch new changes

Tags: git

```
git version 1.7.11.4
3.5.3-1.fc17.x86_64 #1 SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Hello,

When I try and fetch changes from our remote repository I enter the password and then nothing happens, the prompt just returns. I have changes from the remote that I need to merge, but cannot fetch those changes. This is what I have done.

```
git remote show origin
resource_division pushes to resource_division (local out of date)
```

When I try and fetch these changes I get nothing:

```
$ git fetch origin
dev@10.10.10.18's password: 
$
```

I have done the following to try and clean up:

```
git fsck
git clean -f
git gc
```

This used to work and now it has stopped.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git fetch` only retrieves new revisions from the remote server, but does not apply them to your tree.

You have to do a `git merge origin/resource_division` to actually update your branch.

Answer (score 4):

Even easier, a `git pull origin` would fetch *and* merge your changes to your branch.

A [`git pull`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) is a fetch and a merge combined.